# Lumen / Docker / MySQL (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused) But I can connect externally

Tags: php, mysql, docker, lumen

Losing my mind on this one.

I've got a Lumen and MySQL setup in a Docker container. Most everything is good to go.  I can run the container and access Lumen through a browser.  I can access MySQL through Sequel Pro, no problem.  And I can run `php artisan migrate` and it works fine.

But if I try to do anything through Lumen in the browser, it won't connect to the database, and it gives me the Connection refused error.

I'm using Lumen 5.7.7 and .env file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravel-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app
    # container_name:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysqldb
    command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
    volumes:
       - ./schemadump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schemadump.sql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
```

**EDIT:** Ran phpinfo() on the site and on the command line and realized that they aren't even the same version, let alone the same exact details.  Could that be the problem here?  Looking at it more...

Comment: why are you not linking the api and mysqldb services with link. Add the link on api so that it can access the mysqldb. For now i am using link to connect multiple services running on docker but might get deprecated in  the future

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung Thanks!  That helped me realize what was different about the new .yml file I used!  The missing "link" section must have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is working now, sort of. I've got it now working from the browser and not from the command line, which I can work with. From a comment above, it looks like a missing "link" section connecting the api to the database was the issue.  .env file is unchanged, but the docker-compose.yml now looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravel-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: test
      DB_USERNAME: test
      DB_PASSWORD: test
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Added the "environment" section to the api section of the yml file.  That helped out.  And changed the port so it has a different external port compared to the internal port.  Not 100% which part made it work right, but it is working OK for now and I'm not about to change it more.